# Convert integer, signed integer to EBCDIC in java

Tags: java, integer, ascii, encode, ebcdic

How to convert an unsigned integer to EBCDIC format while sending to mainframe, suppose if want to encode 4550 to ebcdic format, below snippet i’m trying, As per the ebcdic chart numbers doesn’t have the equivalent symbol to be encoded and i’m always getting the blank result

```
String s = “4550”;
String e = new String(s.getBytes(),“Cp037");
```

Can someone please help me with the steps to encode it to EBCDIC

Mainframe expecting to be it in encoding format, when they consume the request, numbers field should be unreadable format, here is the example

```
C ¤,G   ÚM        P1234   N
```

fields which are in alphanumeric it’s in readable format and few fields which are in numeric it is encoded with symbols, i’m looking for a way to achieve the same

I found some solutions online which converts integer to packeddecimal to ebcdic format, but it didn't work as expected.

Comment: *String s = “4550”; String e = new String(s.getBytes(),“Cp037");* should have a backing array of 0xF4, 0xF5, 0xF5, 0xF0 for EBCDIC. So `e.getBytes()` should get you that. Does it?

Comment: Integers and packed decimals are binary number formats. You **must not** change encoding of such numbers. It is not clear to me what format the source data is in, and what you format  need to send this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be very clear on what is required on the Mainframe end is it pure text or is it a binary format (e.g. Cobol Comp, comp-3).

Do you need to convert it to EBCDIC. If it is just Text. Just create it as normal Text and let the Mainframe Transfer software do the translation to EBCDIC.

Java strings are 16 bit (i.e. small int) unicode. EBCDIC is a 8 bit char encoding, it is best represented as a Byte array or Stream. To convert a java String to EBCDIC:

```
byte[] ebcdicData = "0123".getBytes("cp037");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, i wanted to encode to comp datatype and i figured out the way of doing it, converting integer to hex and to Cp037 worked, will post the snippet below

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of way of encoding, below is the snippet

```java
int val = Integer.parseInt(input);

if (val >= 0 && val <= 0xffff) {
    hex = String.format("%04x", val);
} else {
    hex = String.format("%08x", val);
}

String[] split = hex.split("(?<=\\G.{" + 2 + "})");

String result = "";
for (String sp : split) {
    byte b1[] = {(byte) Integer.parseInt(sp, 16)};
    result += new String(b1, "Cp037");
}
```

Comment: I'm glad it works but I think there's a little hand waving going on there. Of course per your first sentece, an unsigned integer must begin in Java by being held in a `long`